# Creating scrapy spider that inherits functions from another file base spider class

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to create smaller spiders that inherit functions from another spider.

Here is the code of the main spider:

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
import os.path 


class main(scrapy.Spider):
    allowed_domains = ['domain.com']

    def parse_product_list(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3')]/a/@href").getall()
        for url in urls:
            url = "https:" + url
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_product_view, dont_filter=True)
        # Next Page
        next_page = response.css(".pull-left .pagination a:contains('Next')::attr(href)").get()
        if next_page is not None:
            # yield response.follow_all(url, callback=self.parse)
            # yield from response.follow_all(pagination_links, self.parse)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
        
    def parse_product_view(self, response):
        productSku = response.css("#products_model::text").get().replace("Model #","")
        productName = response.css("#products_name::text").get().replace(";",'') + "- " + productSku
        # productName = '"' + productNameUgly + '"'   
        productDescription = response.css("#productDescription").get().replace(";",'')

        # MSRP Price
        if "$" in response.css("#products_price::text").get():
            productPrice = response.css("#products_price::text").get().replace("$", "")
        else:
            productPrice = response.css("#products_price s::text").get().replace("$", "")

        # Special Price
        if response.css("#products_price .productSpecialPrice::text").get():
            specialPrice = response.css("#products_price .productSpecialPrice::text").get().replace("Sale:$","")
        else:
            specialPrice = ""

        # Product Image
        image = response.css("img.img-responsive.img-fill.product-details-big-thumb::attr(src)").get()
        gallery = response.xpath("//*[@class='product-details-thumb-float']/a/@href").getall()
        gallery.insert(0, image)
        gallery = '; '.join(gallery).replace("wm.php/","")

        
        # Extra Attribute
        if response.xpath(".//*[@class='product-notes-feature']/li").getall():
            key = response.xpath(".//*[@class='product-notes-feature']/li/@data-product-feature").getall()
            value = response.xpath(".//*[@class='product-notes-feature']/li/text()").getall()
            attributes = dict(zip(key, value))
            productAttributes = attributes
            for key, value in attributes.items():
                productAttributes[key] = value.replace(key + ": ", "")


        export_essential = {
            "sku": productSku,
            "label": productSku,
            "name": productName,
            "description": productDescription,
            "price": productPrice,
            "special_price": specialPrice,
            "image": image,
            "media_gallery": gallery
        }

        export_all = export_essential
        if productAttributes:
            export_all.update(productAttributes)

        yield export_all
```

Right now I copy and paste the entire file of the base spider, then change the name and url. This is not an efficient way. If there are changes to the base spider, I have to go back to all the small spiders to update them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but if you change the first lines to:

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.allowed_domains = [url]
```

then you can call this file spider.py, and in another file, say:

```
from spider import Spider

spider1 = Spider('domain.com')
```

s that what you're after?